# TFS SDL 2010 & 2013 but what about 2012?

Tags: sdlc

I see there is a TFS template incorporating SDL (security development lifecycle) for 2013 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42517) but it does not mention anything about TFS2012.

Does anyone know if it is compatible with TFS2012 or if there is an SDL template for 2012? (I don't want to install the 2013 version, only for it to break our TFS2012!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the MSI and took a quick look with Orca. From what I saw, the installer checks explicitly for TFS 2013 and and install an additional Web Service, that, I suppose interacts server-side and, therefore, is version specific.

So your only chance is to upgrade, which, from my experience is not that hard, if you do your homework.